# Como añadir una array en una DB de Laravel en diferentes registros

Tags: php, html, laravel, base-de-datos, formularios

explico rapido lo que quiero hacer. Tengo un formulario el cual guarda en una array los valores de las notas. Quiero insertar esa array en una BD, pero cada posicion en un registro diferente.
**Adjunto Codigo:**

**Formulario**:
 `<td><select style="background-color: #efab3a; border: 1px solid #efab3a;" class="form-select" name="notes[]" id="notes">` Los values son options del 0 al 10.

**Controlador:**

```
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $request->notes; $i++) {
                $notaalu = new AlumneUf;
                $notaalu->alumne_id = $id;
                $notaalu->uf_id = $ufid;
                $notaalu->notes = $request->notes;
                $notaalu->comentaris ="no hi ha comentaris";
                $notaalu ->save();
                return "Agregado";
            }
```

Lo he intentado meter en un for y que cree uno nuevo todo el rato. Pero se queda cargando todo el rato

Answer (score 0):

`$request->notes` tiene toda la pinta de ser un *array*, y tu lo estas intentando tratar como si fuera un sólo número cuando haces esto:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $request->notes; $i++) {
```

Diria que lo que quieres hacer es más bien esto:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($request->notes); $i++) {
```

pues usando la función [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) calculas el número de elementos del array contenido en `$request->notes`.

Y después, para que coja el valor correspondiente al índice iterado (representado por $i) en cada ciclo, cambiar esto:

```
$notaalu->notes = $request->notes;
```

por esto:

```
$notaalu->notes = $request->notes[$i];
```

Ya nos diras si te ha funcionado.